# Cannot save previous data on a table with values

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
public void move_to_another_fragment() {

        Fragment fragment = new ItemFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Items");
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

    }
```

I used above code to move to fragment B from fragment A.In  the fragment A i have table with some data when i come back to frgment A and then move to frgmant B i need to show the table with previous value.Can you explain how i start the fragment b with previous data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your data of Fragment A before changing to Fragment B. And then in the createView function of Fragment B. You could use data saved from the Fragment A to generate the view of Fragment B.

As the activity is same across both the fragments, you can store the data in a class variable of the activity.

Hope this helps.